# Can someone identify the species of this angiosperm?

Tags: species-identification, botany

It seems to be from the pea family (Fabaceae) due to the zygomorphic flowers and the pods. It also has stipules at the base of the composite leaves. It's quite high (~ 80 cm). Photographed in spring in Morocco. It was photographed in a dry riverbed. [image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult one to identify down to the species from the photos. It very much looks like a member of the genus Ononis in the pea family. The leaves, flowers, and seed pods are all characteristic of Ononis. It might be Ononis spinosa, but that is a guess.  The bright sunlight make it difficult to discern many morphological details. I can't see any visible spines on the plant to be certain. Links provided:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ononis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ononis_spinosa